# Angular CLI giving error on Ubuntu that isn't happening on macOS

Tags: angular, ubuntu, angular-cli

When I deploy my app to Ubuntu and run `ng b -prod` it gives the error below, but the exact same project, freshly checked out on either system after an npm install, does NOT give the error on macOS.

Also I've been running for weeks without changing the mentioned CSS files and it was working on the Ubuntu box previously.  Global npm packages were updated on both systems and are the same versions.

It claims that it can't find `'@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css' in '/home/ubuntu/front/src'`, but clearly that file is in node_modules.

The offending line in `src/styles.css` is:

`@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css';`

As I say - this works 100% fine in macOS and worked on this Ubuntu box until this morning.  What's the issue?

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader!./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css' in '/home/ubuntu/front/src'
 @ ./~/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./~/postcss-loader!./src/styles.css 3:10-196
 @ ./src/styles.css
 @ multi ./~/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css ./~/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css ./~/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css ./src/assets/fonts/font-icomoon/style.css ./src/styles.css

ERROR in ./src/styles.css
Module build failed: ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/indigo-pink.css' in '/home/ubuntu/front/src'
    at factoryCallback (/home/ubuntu/front/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:259:39)
    at /home/ubuntu/front/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:234:19
    at onDoneResolving (/home/ubuntu/front/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:59:20)
    at /home/ubuntu/front/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:126:20
    at /home/ubuntu/front/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3824:9
    at /home/ubuntu/front/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:460:16
    at iteratorCallback (/home/ubuntu/front/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:1032:13)
    at /home/ubuntu/front/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:944:16
    at /home/ubuntu/front/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:3821:13
    at apply (/home/ubuntu/front/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:21:25)
    at /home/ubuntu/front/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:56:12
    at /home/ubuntu/front/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:121:22
    at onResolved (/home/ubuntu/front/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:70:11)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/ubuntu/front/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)
    at afterInnerCallback (/home/ubuntu/front/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:138:10)
    at loggingCallbackWrapper (/home/ubuntu/front/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/createInnerCallback.js:31:19)

ERROR in /home/ubuntu/front/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/loader.js??ref--9-0!/home/ubuntu/front/node_modules/style-loader/index.js!/home/ubuntu/front/node_modules/css-loader/index.js?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!/home/ubuntu/front/node_modules/postcss-loader/index.js!/home/ubuntu/front/src/styles.css doesn't export content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe, because you're using different version of Angular Material 2.
in version beta.3 you need change pre-built theme with this link

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

The document here: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/guides/theming.md#using-a-pre-built-theme

Comment: Wow - thanks.  Obviously I made an error and hadn't cleanly updated my dev environment.  You're a life saver!

Comment: I'm glad to help!